# Derive Array of complex type from column values

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I need to create ADF workflow such that:
input column name "phone" which contains phone number results in below:

```
contact[0].number = "xxxxxxxxxx"
contact[0].type = "phone"
```

and "mobile" column results in:

```
contact[1].number = "xxxxxxxxxx"
contact[1].type = "mobile"
```

We get "phone" and "mobile" in all the input rows.

The source is Azure SQL Database.

I need to sink this into blob storage in json file.

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Use the array syntax with 2 structures
[@(number = Phone, type = 'Phone'),@(number = Mobile,type = 'Mobile')]

Answer (score 0):

Use a Derived Column in data flows and build your structure inside the expression builder. Call your top-level structure "contacts". Now use an Aggregate transformation to create an array of your rows of structs using the collect() function. Here are some examples:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zneE18EHJSE
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oAEh21NFgWQ

Comment: How can I add both Mobile and Phone to the top-level structure contact?
for Column contacts I added below expression: 
@(number=Phone,  type='Phone')